# trying to create a COMPOUND TRIGGER but got Error pls-00103

Tags: plsql

i tried to create a trigger to suppress undesired updates, but go t the error :
 `ora-04091 table is mutating trigger/function may not see it`
i did some research and found out that i need to use a compound trigger,
the i have now is

```
create or replace TRIGGER CHECK_SOLD_OPERATION_UPDATE
FOR UPDATE OF ENGAGED ON FICHE_ENGAGE_DEP 
COMPOUND TRIGGER
--BEFORE EACH ROW IS BEGIN END BEFORE EACH ROW;

    sold number;
BEFORE STATEMENT IS
BEGIN
    select sold_operation(id_operation)-:NEW.engaged+nvl(:OLD.engaged,0) as sold into sold
    from operation
    where id_operation=:NEW.id_operation;
END BEFORE STATEMENT;

AFTER EACH ROW IS
BEGIN
    if (sold<0 AND :NEW.type_fiche>2) THEN --do not insert
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20101, 'ERROR!!!');
        --ROLLBACK;
    END IF;    
END AFTER EACH ROW;
END CHECK_SOLD_OPERATION_UPDATE;
```

now i have this error
`PLS-00679: trigger binds not allowed in before/after statement section`
any thoughts on what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: look at this example - https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/trigger-enhancements-11gr1  you need to store the items you need to keep track of in some sort of collection, then reference/iterate through that collection in the AFTER EACH ROW section

Comment: Additionally you cannot access the pseudo records :NEW or :OLD in the Statement level section of the compound level trigger. The only exist in the row level sections.